# Identifying table causing runaway rollback in MySQL 5.5 (InnoDB / Windows)

Tags: mysql, innodb, mysql-5.5, windows, rollback

I have a large database (180 GB), running under Windows, with a runaway rollback that starts running as soon as the database is started up.

I have started the database with `innodb_force_recovery=3` to prevent the rollback from running while I try to fix the problem.  As I understand it from other questions on StackExchange, the correct thing to do is to drop the table causing the rollback and restore it from a backup.  All that would be no problem. However, I am unable to identify the table triggering the rollback. `SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS` is no help -- it just says that there is a rollback. I am running mysqlcheck over all the tables, but everything is so far showing up "OK".

Is there any way to determine what table(s) are causing the rollback?

Comment: What does SHOW BINARY LOGS; send back?

Comment: What monster query was running when it crashed?  If it does not get rolled back, you will have trash in the table(s).